# How to create ul li elements from nested JSON data in HTML DROPDOWN

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

[image]

But below is what I could find on internet. I want to create something like above. Below is the code snippet. It works totally fine. But how can I make it dynamic. I mean if I add ul and li manually the tree gets rendered correctly. But I want that to happen as per the JSON received from REST API. How to add ul and li elements from nested JSON data. Can someone please help me.

**Working Code Link:**
http://jsfiddle.net/jddevight/esS4k/

**Working Code snippet:**

```
var dropdown = $("#dropdown").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: [{ text: "", value: "" }],
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    open: function (e) {
        // If the treeview is not visible, then make it visible.
        if (!$treeviewRootElem.hasClass("k-custom-visible")) {
            $treeviewRootElem.slideToggle('fast', function() {
                dropdown.close();
                $treeviewRootElem.addClass("k-custom-visible");
            });
        }
    }
}).data("kendoDropDownList");
var $dropdownRootElem = $(dropdown.element).closest("span.k-dropdown");

var treeview = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    select: function (e) {
        // When a node is selected, display the text for the node in the dropdown and hide the treeview.
        $dropdownRootElem.find("span.k-input").text($(e.node).children("div").text());
        $treeviewRootElem.slideToggle('fast', function() {
            $treeviewRootElem.removeClass("k-custom-visible");
        });
    }
}).data("kendoTreeView");
var $treeviewRootElem = $(treeview.element).closest("div.k-treeview");

// Hide the treeview.
$treeviewRootElem
    .width($dropdownRootElem.width())
    .css({ "border":"1px solid grey", "display": "none", "position": "absolute" });

// Position the treeview so that it is below the dropdown.
$treeviewRootElem
    .css({ "top": $dropdownRootElem.position().top + $dropdownRootElem.height(), "left": $dropdownRootElem.position().left });

$(document).click(function(e) {
    // Ignore clicks on the treetriew.
    if ($(e.target).closest("div.k-treeview").length == 0) {
        // If visible, then close the treeview.
        if ($treeviewRootElem.hasClass("k-custom-visible")) {
            $treeviewRootElem.slideToggle('fast', function() {
                $treeviewRootElem.removeClass("k-custom-visible");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="treeview">
    <li data-expanded="true">Item 1
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1.1</li>
            <li>Item 1.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-expanded="true">Item 2
        <ul>
            <li data-expanded="true">Item 2.1
             <ul>
            <li>Item 1.1</li>
            <li>Item 1.2</li>
        </ul></li>
            <li>Item 2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<input id="dropdown"></input>
```

Comment: where is you ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't initialize treeview on ul element. Instead use div element. Then use datasource to assign data from json.

```
var treeview = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  dataSource : [
    {
      "id"   :100,
      "text" :"tree",
      "items":[...
```

To update data simply call dataStore.data(newData).

```
treeview.dataSource.data([
  { text: "bar", items: [
    { text: "baz" }
  ] }
]);
```

Here's example how to that: http://jsfiddle.net/m2Lpw52g/

Comment: Many Thanks for help!

Comment: Shall the `input "dropdown" tag` should be inside the `div treeview tag`. Can you kindly see your fiddle example.

Comment: Dropdown element can't be inside treeview div element. They are two separate components that are connected via script to work together.